# Matching one line from continuous stream in Linux shell

Tags: bash

How can I make the following commands exit immediately after the first line is matched? I understand that SIGPIPE is not sent to `cat` until it tries to write next time ([tail bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13183)), but I don't understand how to solve this issue.

```
cat <( echo -ne "asdf1\nzxcv1\nasdf2\n"; sleep 5; echo -ne "zxcv2\nasdf3\n" ) | grep --line-buffered zxcv | head --lines=1
cat <( echo -ne "asdf1\nzxcv1\nasdf2\n"; sleep 5; echo -ne "zxcv2\nasdf3\n" ) | grep --max-count=1 zxcv
```

NB: I actually had `tail --follow` before the pipesign, but replaced it with `cat`and `sleep` to simplify testing. The shell in question is GNU bash 4.4.12(1)-release, and I'm running MINGW that came with Git-for-Windows 2.12.2.2.

CLARIFICATION: I have a jboss server which is started in a docker container and which outputs couple thousand lines of text within three minutes to a log file. My goal is to watch this file until a status line is printed, analyze line contents and return it to a human or Jenkins user. Of course, I can grep whole file and sleep for a second in a loop, but I'd rather avoid this if at all possible. Furthermore, this looping would interfere with my usage of timeout routine to limit maximum execution time. So, is it possible to listen for a pipe until a certain line appears and stop as soon as that happens?

Related question: [Why does bash ignore SIGINT if its currently running child handles it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287044/why-does-bash-ignore-sigint-if-its-currently-running-child-handles-it)

Comment: I use tail to follow a log file, and cat+sleep is a good approximation of how tail -f behaves itself, which also happens to be easier to test.

Comment: I don't even understand what you are trying to do, or why.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I've verified that `head` dies after printing the first line (removed background job noise):

```
$ (printf '%s\n' a b a; sleep 5; printf '%s\n' a) | grep --line-buffered a | head --lines=1 & sleep 1; pstree $$
a
bash─┬─bash───sleep
     ├─grep
     └─pstree
```

At first glance, it appears `head` doesn't send SIGPIPE, but I get conflicting information from running `strace grep`:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' a b a; sleep 10; printf '%s\n' a) | strace grep --line-buffered a | head --lines=1
…
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=21950, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

… and `kill`ing `grep`:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' a b a; sleep 10; printf '%s\n' a) | grep --line-buffered a | head --lines=1 & sleep 1; kill -PIPE $(pgrep grep); sleep 5; pstree $$
a
bash─┬─bash───sleep
     └─pstree
```

Killing `grep` and then `sleep` fixes the issue:

```
$ (printf '%s\n' a b a; sleep 10; printf '%s\n' a) | grep --line-buffered a | head --lines=1 & sleep 1; kill -PIPE $(pgrep grep); sleep 1; kill -PIPE $(pgrep sleep); sleep 5; pstree $$
a
bash───pstree
```

Conclusion: WTF?

Comment: I believe SIGPIPE is sent by kernel to grep as soon as grep tries to write something to head, but this happens first after text producer awakens from sleep and writes something to grep. So, if you kill grep too soon, it will not get SIGPIPE, but if you wait for producer to print something, you'll see that grep exits by itself due to SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing following to be able to break following log both on a matching line and after a timeout.

```
#!/bin/sh

TOP_PID=$$
container_id="$1"
LOG_PATH=/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log

await_startup () {
  status=$(check_status)
  follow_log --timeout $timeout &
  local bgjob_pid; local bgjob_status;
  bgjob_pid=$(jobs -p)
  test -n "$bgjob_pid" || die "Could not start background job to follow log."
  bgjob_status=true
  while [ "$status" = "not started" ] && $bgjob_status; do
    sleep 1s
    status=$(check_status)
    if kill -0 $bgjob_pid 2>/dev/null; then
      bgjob_status=true
    else
      bgjob_status=false
    fi
  done
  kill -KILL $bgjob_pid 2>/dev/null
}

follow_log () {
  # argument parsing skipped...
  docker exec $container_id timeout $timeout tail --follow=name ---disable-inotify --max-unchanged-stats=2 /$LOG_PATH
}

check_status () {
  local line;
  line=$(docker exec $container_id grep --extended-regexp --only-matching 'JBoss EAP .+ started.+in' /$LOG_PATH | tail --lines=1)
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    printf "not started"
  elif printf "%s" "$line" | grep --quiet "with errors"; then
    printf "started and unhealthy"
  else
    printf "healthy"
  fi
}

die () {
  test -n "$1" && printf "%s\n" "$1"
  kill -s TERM $TOP_PID
  return 1
} 1>&2
```